# Many-to-many recursive relation

Tags: entity-framework, recursion, many-to-many

I'm trying to add many-to-many recursive relation within given entity in entity framework. My problem is that I can't add additional properties in the table "MyEntityTable". Here is the code snippet:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
.HasMany(a => a.ParentTransportUnits)
.WithMany(b => b.ChildTransportUnits)
.Map(mc => { mc.ToTable("MyEntityTable");
mc.MapLeftKey("ParentColumn");
mc.MapRightKey("ChildColumn"); });
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the concrete error here?

Comment: There is no particular error here, but is it possible to add custom properties (columns) in this table, "MyEntityTable"?